# Where can I find Epson Perfection V500 scanner drivers

Tags: drivers, scanner

Epson discontinued support of Linux drivers for the Perfection V500 Photo scanner at the end of 2012. I have reviewed the older answers (2012) for this question and have the list of needed drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My question, where can I find them now?

Answer (score 0):

You can download these drivers form the [Epson Website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule), the driver date is 06-20-2013.

Install these drivers and restart your scanner.  Make sure that you download the right driver for your system, either the 32bit or 64bit.